# Apply a 2-Second delay on the menu drop-drop bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, magento

I'm trying to achieve a two seconds delay on my magento dropdown submenu items only when  i hover parent item. But i figure some issues.

**Here I have a jQuery for 1st menu item. So when I will hover the item, its submenu will be shown after two seconds. My jQuery is:**

```
jQuery(".level0.nav-1").mouseover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(".level0.nav-1 .dropdown-container.left").show();
    }, 2000);
});
jQuery(".level0.nav-1").mouseout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(".level0.nav-1 .dropdown-container.left").hide();
    }, 0);
});
```

The problem is that the submenu don't dissapear instantly after I make a mouse out action. Only If I re mouse over the item and mouse out.
 Can someone help me with this problem? I will be glad to learn a new method, another than my method.(Which is actually not so good I guess).

Comment: try using mouseenter/mouseleave, and don't need setTimout in mouseleave

Comment: `$(".level0.nav-1 .dropdown-container.left").delay(2000).fadeIn();` & remove `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add the same "mouseout" event to the 2nd-level tier as well but without the 2-second delay?

For example:

```
jQuery(".level0.nav-1 .dropdown-container.left").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use "blur" ?

```
$( ".level0.nav-1" ).blur(function() {})
```

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: Since blur is just losing focus (just one event), if you have the focus of second menu and lose it, it will disappear faster.